# Clicking element to change slick slider

Tags: html, jquery, css, slick.js

I have a section where the first row are logos and the second row are quotes associated to those logos.

On each logo click, I want it to switch over to the quote associated to that logo / company.

I have tried `asNavFor`, but it doesn't work as intended (see demo).

For demo and simplicity purposes, I'll just using text to showcase my issue below.

In my demo below, this is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

- The `triggers` at the top are essentially my logos. The center logo (trigger 2) is the slick slide that is active by default.
- When a user clicks on another trigger (say trigger 3), I want the text in `div` below to match that slide (so it should say "Slide 3 (for trigger 3)").

**Note**: the reason I'm using `slick.js` is because a user is able to drag the bottom div to change slide also (and use slick arrows)

Code:

```js
$(function(){

  const nav = $("#section_navi");
  const slider = $("#section__slick");


/*   $(nav).slick({
   slidesToShow: 3,
   slidesToScroll: 3,
   arrows: false,
   fade: true,
   asNavFor: slider
  }); */

  $(slider).slick({
    arrows: false,
    dots: false,
    mobileFirst: true,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    infinite: true,
    /* asNavFor: nav */
 });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section class="section">
  <div class="section__inner">

    <!-- nav -->
    <div class="section__nav" id="section_navi">
      <span class="section__image">Trigger 1</span>
      <span class="section__image">Trigger 2</span>
      <span class="section__image">Trigger 3</span>
    </div>
    
    <!-- slides -->
    <div class="section__cards" id="section__slick">
      <div class="card">Slide 1 (for trigger 1)</div>
      <div class="card">Slide 2 (for trigger 2)</div>
      <div class="card">Slide 3 (for trigger 3)</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It is easy, you won't even require another plugin for that.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.trigger li').on('click', function() {
  $('.trigger li').removeClass('active');
  $('.slider li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  debugger;
  var index=parseInt($(this).attr('data-trigger'));
  $($('.slider li')[index-1]).addClass('active')
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.trigger {
  display: flex;
}

.trigger li {
  flex: 1;
}

.trigger li.active {
  color: blue;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}

.slider li {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.slider li:nth-child(3n+1) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.slider li:nth-child(3n+2) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.slider li:nth-child(3n+3) {
  background-color: red;
}

.slider li.active {
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
    <ul class="trigger">
        <li data-trigger="1">Trigger 1</li>
        <li data-trigger="2" class="active">Trigger 2</li>
        <li data-trigger="3">Trigger 3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="slider">
        <li>Slide 1</li>
        <li class="active">Slide 2</li>
        <li>Slide 3</li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Check this out, I have not used any plugins.

Comment: Hi Abin, I'm looking for this to work with slick slider. Reason being, the user can also swipe the bottom div (or use the slick arrows) to change slide also.